# Find and identify single pixel thin contours in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, contour

I'm trying to find the pixel locations for each "boundary" in [this image](https://postimg.cc/8FVvDNJ9) (and similar ones). Unfortunately, `cv2.findContours` doesn't work, perhaps because the boundaries are quite thin.

Alternatively, I've tried `findContours` with [this image](https://postimg.cc/JDF4r5Y0) (the first image is obtained after running an edge algorithm on this), and while it does return the [contours](https://postimg.cc/Jt94SKBd), I have no idea how to separate the contours and get the pixel values from it. This method also returns an outlining rectangle (closed contours?) that I don't want. I'd be happy with open contours.

I'd like to be able to separate out the individual lines and assign a label to each of them.

Is there any way to get open contours for each line and be able to get the pixels for them?

**EDIT:** Here are a couple of examples of the [original images](https://postimg.cc/gallery/MTr6MXj). I'm trying to create a dataset containing the layer boundaries (approximates work just fine) and labels of each of the "layers" in the images. The dataset is meant to train a deep learning network.

**EDIT 2:** The images posted here are OCT images of the retina. The layers are the retinal layers. I'm trying to add rough automatic labels for the unlabeled data, to augment manual labels that contain the layer boundaries.

Comment: findContours is for finding edges, not ridges. you have ridges in the first picture. findContours will extract a closed contour around each of your lines. *stop* using Canny, it does not apply here. don't use kmeans either. none of that leads to a solution. it only looks fancy. -- provide untouched source data.

Comment: explain your goal. https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I've edited to explain my goal and uploaded the original images.

Comment: that's OCT, probably pictures of eyes/retinas. the "layers" are anatomical features. you  seem to want to determine the thickness of that. that's the level of explanation you should strive for. -- you don't want contours for this. it is also pointless to train a DNN on automatically labeled data. if the automatic labeling were good, you wouldn't need a DNN. if it's rubbish, the labeling is useless for training a DNN.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Yes, it's OCT. The reason for getting automatically labelled data is to use it in a semi-supervised network, which needs both "strong" and 'weak" labels. The existing dataset already has manual labels. The goal is to augment it with automatic labels.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz You make a fair point about the thickness of the layers, but I'm trying to make something consistent with the manual labels. The manual labels only consist of the layer boundaries.

Comment: median blur and thresholding will probably segment these pictures tolerably. you want a segmentation for training the DNN because any contours would be converted to segmentations (binary maps) anyway.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I see. How do you suggest I go about the thresholding? For the different layers, I mean? Since the layers differ in intensities.
If it's not too much trouble, could you provide a toy solution as an answer?